# application: continueUserActivity: restorationHandler: not called in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios11

I have a Voip app with callkit integrated. It worked fine in iOS 10 and now I seem to have issues with iOS 11 when calling from native recents (iOS recents).

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willContinueUserActivityWithType:(nonnull NSString *)userActivityType {}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(nonnull NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:(nonnull void (^)(NSArray * _Nullable))restorationHandler {}
```

Both these methods are not called and hence I am not able to process the NSUserActivity INStartAudioCallIntent. Am I missing something obvious that has changed in iOS 11?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Verify the **remoteHandle and supportedHandleTypes**, both should be similar as per your requirement.

```
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = [[CXHandle alloc] initWithType:CXHandleTypeGeneric value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", phoneno]];
```

---

```
    configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:CXHandleTypeGeneric],[NSNumber numberWithInteger:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber], nil];
```

If the handles mismatches, you can't able to process the NSUserActivity.

Comment: Man..you saved me after keeping searching for more than 1 hour.

Comment: strangely this "supportedHandleTypes" line is missing from almost all tutorials on CallKit. thanks a bunch

Comment: This is really a life saver tip. Thanks a ton!