# Cordova iOS CallKit - calls from phone call history (Recents tab) stopped working

Tags: ios, cordova, callkit

I'm working on a VoIP iOS app based on WebRTC and Cordova platform. We make heavy use of CallKit API, which adds each call made with our app to phone's call history. When tapped on our call, iOS should run our application and pass call intent to it, and it used to work perfectly well. I didn't notice when it stopped working - probably after updating to iOS 10.

What I already have:

1. In the .plist file:

`<key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
<array>
  <string>INStartAudioCallIntent</string>
</array>`

2. Call Intent extension. It works OK, when initiating calls with Siri, but doesn't run on tapping on call history record.
3. Implemented `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler` in the app's delegate. Again, it works good, when calling with Siri.

Does anybody have an idea what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer this answer: [continueuseractivity not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051359/application-continueuseractivity-restorationhandler-not-called-in-ios-11/46077628#46077628)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46051359/application-continueuseractivity-restorationhandler-not-called-in-ios-11/46077628#46077628) helped.

I needed to add `supportedHandleTypes` to my CXProviderConfiguration.

Swift:

`configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [CXHandle.HandleType.generic, CXHandle.HandleType.phoneNumber]`

Objective C:

`configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:CXHandleTypeGeneric],[NSNumber numberWithInteger:CXHandleTypePhoneNumber], nil];`