# make voip call from phone call log in iOS

Tags: ios, callkit

In my **Voip** application I am using **callkit** to receive incoming call.
by using the below method:

```
-(void)reportIncomingCall:(NSUUID*)UDID handle:(NSString*)handle{
```

I can see the log of this incoming call in call history of my *iPhone* native call application.

I wanted to make outgoing call from the *iPhone* native call application. I works for *WhatsApp, hangout* and etc applications. But, not able to wake up my application when I try calling the user from incoming call log.

```
- (NSUUID *)reportOutgoingCallContactIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier destination:(NSString *)name telNumber:(NSString *)telnum
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to create Intents Extension for your target, in order to handle audio calls from native call history.

In Xcode:

> File -> New -> Target

Select **Intents Extension**

Here is the main class for the extension, this is how it should look like

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, INStartAudioCallIntentHandling {

func handle(intent: INStartAudioCallIntent, completion: @escaping (INStartAudioCallIntentResponse) -> Void) {
    let response: INStartAudioCallIntentResponse
    defer {
        completion(response)
    }

    // Ensure there is a person handle
    guard intent.contacts?.first?.personHandle != nil else {
        response = INStartAudioCallIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil)
        return
    }

    let userActivity = NSUserActivity(activityType: String(describing: INStartAudioCallIntent.self))

    response = INStartAudioCallIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: userActivity)
    } 
}
```

Than, you need to provide the URLScheme for your app in order to start a VoIP call when the app delegate receives the openURL

Here is the extension for the NSUserActivity to help you detect the start call intent

```
import Intents

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
protocol SupportedStartCallIntent {
    var contacts: [INPerson]? { get }
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension INStartAudioCallIntent: SupportedStartCallIntent {}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
extension NSUserActivity {

    var startCallHandle: String? {
        guard let startCallIntent = interaction?.intent as? SupportedStartCallIntent else {
            return nil
        }
        return startCallIntent.contacts?.first?.personHandle?.value
    }

}
```

You also need to register your URL scheme in your target settings:

Xcode target settings, select Info card, and on the bottom URL Types, select +
to add new type and give it a name, like `VoIPCall`

In `AppDelegate` override the following function

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
               continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
               restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {

    if userActivity.startCallHandle {
        // START YOUR VOIP CALL HERE ----
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for swift 5 you should define  continueuseractivity function to SceneDelegate.swift

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {

    let interaction = userActivity.interaction
    if let startAudioCallIntent = interaction?.intent as? INStartAudioCallIntent{

        let contact = startAudioCallIntent.contacts?.first
    
        let contactHandle = contact?.personHandle

            if let phoneNumber = contactHandle?.value {
               print(phoneNumber)
            //Your call logic
            }
 
    }
    return
}
```

please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68773574/9346859)